# Как декодировать спарсенный текст

Tags: python-3.x, requests-html

Пытаюсь спарсить информацию с сайта едадил на Python. И все бы ничего, но на выходе я получаю частично текст в перемешку с символами. Вот ссылка откуда я получаю текст https://api.edadeal.ru/web/search/offers?count=30&locality=moskva&page=1&retailer=5ka
Пользуюсь библиотекой request-html. Текст при считывании записываю в файл html.
По итогу перепробовал записывать в разных в кодировках, но все тщетно...

Если кто сталкивался с похожей проблемой, просьба помочь ) так как у самого уже закончились идеи для решения проблемы )

```py
url = "https://api.edadeal.ru/web/search/offers?count=30&locality=moskva&page=1&retailer=5ka"
session = HTMLSession()
headers = {
    'accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
    'accept': '*/*'
}

payload = ""
cookies = {
    'cookies': "_ym_d=1634539717; _ym_uid=1634539717596492805; _ym_isad=2; yandexuid=7052871531591888111; "
               "yuidss=7052871531591888111; yandex_login=v.korovanskaya; gdpr=0; "
               "Session_id=3:1634659617.5.3.1593514547343:dYdUXw:4.1|1096681392.0.2|159148231.715225.2.2:715225"
               "|1071645053.2594868.2.2:2594868|1194122161.9069132.2.2:9069132|569155494.12441853.2.2:12441853"
               "|1412182437.25318834.2.2:25318834|46:27709.531774.r3dFXJ0CwRge_gOO8CIXZ245a8w; "
               "mda2_beacon=1634659617120; "
               "edadeal_auth=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9"
               ".eyJkdWlkIjoiODg0OWQ4NjktMGI1Mi00NDhjLThkNmQtOGFiMTVmNzljNmNlIiwidWlkIjoiMDAwMDAwMDAtMDAwMC0wMDAwLTAwMDAtMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwIiwiYWlkIjoiMDAwMDAwMDAtMDAwMC0wMDAwLTAwMDAtMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwIiwibXJnIjp0cnVlLCJhdWQiOiJ1c3IiLCJleHAiOjE2NjYxMDczNzEsImp0aSI6ImNiNDYzZWIxLTc4MWYtNGZhYy05OGU5LWQ3ZTE5MGYyY2MwZSIsImlhdCI6MTYzNDY1Nzc3MSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly91c3IuZWRhZGVhbC5ydSIsIm5iZiI6MTYzNDY1Nzc3MSwic3ViIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly91c3IuZWRhZGVhbC5ydSJ9.lR4453_ZCr0Unax2etDExUl8eBhlg7hltcIuMLFFpicZ1Ph9PZ8uDa_Pp4iUtz9slBRuUKbM4ICwHnRC_G0DxSztm54j4cBwvpOE4fsD7bLj8k-dzCNfXEmj1ARCCpKQdRC53rbYUTY_D_Mx1W_HuwxG45Oi0W8s_-5GrzcMKoA; yp=1635245248.yu.7052871531591888111; ymex=1637750848.oyu.7052871531591888111; _ym_visorc=w; edid=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzUxMiJ9.eyJkdWlkIjoiYzBhNTI1MmZkZDFmNDEyNmIwYTk1NGNiMDk1ZDg3MDQiLCJ2cnQiOjEsImV4cCI6MTkzNjk1NDA1NSwibmJmIjoxNjM1MTU4ODM1fQ.o4seFvaRIwaIbv3FyfnNQ7EUiIpIt6j9ODOaxHdqkXY5SJLiqm_8hkme1EEAMumL1-AViiVlZ1a3W2oRh2gjl2vMIpbdVN7KBMahZ-CK1qRiTZ_-snNT6H883Oiuo2kZ_fyuBkg-j27IeNzJkMUhZg7LkFn3tJbp8LohcrZvmcE"}

print(session.get(url, headers=headers).text)
with open('page.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.write(session.get(url, headers=headers).text)`
```

[image: Получаемый текст]

Answer (score 0):

Используйте библиотеку **playwright**

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
```

Пример запроса

```
with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto(https://edadeal.ru/sankt-peterburg/offers?q=молоко)
    content = page.content()
```

Переменная *content* содержит содержимое html-страницы :)